# PHP Array comes out backwards

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

This is my current output from a preg_match_all

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => 2 Sentence text here
    )

)

Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => 3 Sentence text here.
        [1] => 4 Sentence text here.
        [2] => 5 Sentence text here.
    )

)
```

I'm trying to insert each output as a new row in a table but it's thinking that each [0] [1] [2] is a new column. How do I insert the array into mysql?

```
$query = "INSERT INTO table (col1) VALUES ";
foreach ($matches as $item) {
$query .= "('".$item[0]."'),";
}
$query = rtrim($query,",");
$result = mysql_query($query);
```

The above obviously only inserts the first row in of the array

Comment: can you show what your `$query` content looks like before you pass it to mysql_query?

Comment: what does $matches contain?

Comment: So many things wrong with this, I don't even know where to begin.

Comment: _Insert obligatory "please use [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) instead of mysql" comment here_

Comment: I don't understand how the question relates to the title. :confused:

Answer (score 1):

Well, you have an array in other array, so...

```
$query = "INSERT INTO table (col1) VALUES ";

if(!empty($matches))
{
    foreach ($matches as $item) {
        foreach ($item[0] as $items) {
            $query .= "('".$items."'),";
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
if(!empty($matches))
{
    foreach ($matches[0] as $item) {
        $query .= "('".$item."'),";
    }
}
```

Depends on how you are getting your array matches.

---

```
$query = rtrim($query,",");
$result = mysql_query($query);
```

That way you'll get this query:

```
INSERT INTO table (col1) VALUES ('2 Sentence text here'), ('3 Sentence text here'), ('4 Sentence text here'), ('5 Sentence text here')
```

Which is a valid way to insert several values in one column with a single INSERT statement.

**Note:**
[Please, don't use mysql_* functions in new code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [red box](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo), or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Comment: Note that if his $matches array is empty, this will crash.

Comment: @ChadPriddle, What output this gives you: `mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error())` and/or this: `echo $query;`

Comment: INSERT INTO table (col1) VALUES

Comment: @ChadPriddle, the arrays at the top of your question. Are they in an array? Or those arrays represents different matches? What you get with `print_r($matches)`?

Comment: @LuigiSiri the opt example is what print_r($matches) is outputting

Comment: Does it outputs both arrays or those arrays represents different matches? @ChadPriddle?